# Como obtener el numero del dia de la semana PL SQL ORACLE sin importar el lenguaje

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date

la idea es poder obtener el numero de la semana en una funcion en ORACLE pero que esta siempre me devuelva los mismos valores sin importa la configuracion de idioma para no dar calculos errados en las fechas,

por ejemplo 
español:

```
  L M M J V S D
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Ingles:

```
  D L M M j V S
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

la funcion que tengo para esto es:

```
  to_number(to_char(parametro_fecha,'D'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcion para validar esto siempre en un mismo lenguaje se valida con la configuracion de idioma en el TO_CHAR

```
 to_number(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(p_fecha, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'))
```

Se coloca **ENGLISH** si se quiere que el dia Domingo sea igual a 1

o

**SPANISH** si se quiere que el dia Lunes sea igual a 1

```
 to_number(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(p_fecha, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=SPANISH'))
```

Comment: He probado esta solución pero en ambos casos, con Inglés y Español, colocando la fecha 2020-10-05 me devuelve 1 o sea Lunes

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que queremos representar el 5 de octubre de 2020 que era lunes como puedes ver aquí https://www.calendario-365.es/calendario/2020/octubre.html:

```
 select TO_DATE('2020-10-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
```

Ese formato hace que la cadena represente al día 5 de octubre de 2020, lunes, y luego ya puedes pintarla como quieras , pero siempre sera ese día:

```
   select TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('2020-10-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'D' ) from dual;
    select TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('2020-10-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=SPANISH') from dual;
    select TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('2020-10-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') from dual;
```

Supongamos que queremos representar el 10 de mayo de 2020 que era domingo como puede ver aquí https://www.calendario-365.es/calendario/2020/mayo.html:

```
select TO_DATE('2020-10-05', 'YYYY-DD-MM') from dual;
```

ese formateo hace que la cadena represente al dia 10 de mayo  de 2020 domingo y luego ya puedes pintarla como quieras , pero siempre sera ese día:

```
select TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('2020-10-05', 'YYYY-DD-MM') , 'D' ) from dual;
select TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('2020-10-05', 'YYYY-DD-MM') , 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=SPANISH') from dual;
select TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('2020-10-05', 'YYYY-DD-MM') , 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') from dual;
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).