# Escribir una función para verificar si una fecha cae en fin de semana o no

Tags: funciones, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo una duda, necesito crear una función que me verifique si una fecha cae dentro de un fin de semana o no. Hice la siguiente función, pero me un error...

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FIN_SEMANA
  (FECHA date)
  return date
IS

BEGIN
   if TO_CHAR(FECHA,'DD/MM/YYYY', 'DD') IN ('SAT', 'Sun') then
     dbms_output.put_line('Es fin de Semana');
  else
      dbms_output.put_line('No es fin de semana');
  end if;
END;
```

ORA-01830: la máscara de formato de fecha termina antes de convertir toda la cadena de entrada 01830. 00000 - "date format picture ends before converting entire input string" *Cause:
*Action:

Answer (score 2):

Creo que estás implementando mal `TO_CHAR`, además que `DD` trae el número de día del mes (1, 30), no de la semana, ni el nombre del día.

Si el campo FECHA es `DATE` o `DATETIME`, se puede extraer el valor.

```
TO_CHAR(FECHA, 'D')
```

Si el campo es un string (`VARCHAR`, ...) hay que hacer una conversión previa, por ejemplo:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2021-12-26', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'D')
```

[+] `D` - Numero de día de semana (1-7) | `DY` - Nombre de dia de semana (DOM, LUN... o SUN, MON, ... ) (*) Tener cuidado con esta última opción por temas de compatibilidad al migrar a otro servidor.
Ver [tabla de formatos](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm).

Adicional, [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75387/como-obtener-el-numero-del-dia-de-la-semana-pl-sql-oracle-sin-importar-el-lengua) y [esta otra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450965/determine-if-oracle-date-is-on-a-weekend) te pueden servir de referencia.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda...!!!